# how to read wav files one after other from the same folder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, wav

I am trying to write a program where i have to read a wav file, extract some features from it and save them and then go and pick the next file repeat the same procedure. the number of wave files to be picked are more than 100. Can someone help me how to read wavfiles one after another. (say the files are named e1.wav,e2.wav and so on). someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dir` command is quite helpful here. It either displays the whole content of a directory but you can also specify a glob to just return a sub-set of files, e.g. `dir('*.wav')`. This returns an struct-array containing file information such as `name`, `date`, `bytes`, `isdir` and so on.

To get started, try the following:

```
filelist = dir('*.wav');
for file = filelist
    fprintf('Processing %s\n', file.name);
    fid = fopen(file.name);
    % Do something here with your file.
    fclose(fid);
end
```

**Edit 1:** Change the double-quotes to single-quotes (thx to [user1540393](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540393/user1540393)).

**Edit 2** (Suggested by [amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro)): If a processing result has to be stored per file, 
I often use the following pattern. I usually pre-allocate an array, a struct array or 
a cell array of the same size as the filelist. Then I use an integer index to iterate 
over the file list, which I can also use to write the output. If the information to be
stored is homogeneous (e.g. one scalar per file), use an array or a struct array. 
However, if the information differs from file to file (e.g. vectors or matrices of different size) use a cell array instead.

An example using an ordinary array:

```
filelist = dir('*.wav');
% Pre-allocate an array to store some per-file information.
result = zeros(size(filelist));
for index = 1 : length(filelist)
    fprintf('Processing %s\n', filelist(index).name);
    % Read the sample rate Fs and store it.
    [y, Fs] = wavread(filelist(index).name);
    result(index) = Fs;
end
% result(1) .. result(N) contain the sample rates of each file.
```

An example using a cell array:

```
filelist = dir('*.wav');
% Pre-allocate a cell array to store some per-file information.
result = cell(size(filelist));
for index = 1 : length(filelist)
    fprintf('Processing %s\n', filelist(index).name);
    % Read the data of the WAV file and store it.
    y = wavread(filelist(index).name);
    result{index} = y;
end
% result{1} .. result{N} contain the data of the WAV files.
```

Comment: Its working except that single quotes must be used instead of double qoutes in fprintf statement.. Thank You Mehrwolf

Comment: Fixed the quotes. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Maybe you can use `wavread` to open the wav-files:  http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html. See also `wavwrite` : http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/wavwrite.html

Comment: @H.Muster: My example was just intended to get started with a sequence of files. I think your approach of using `wavread` together with the `dir` command is pretty much the way to go with WAV files.

Comment: @Mehrwolf: you should also mention initializing a matrix or a cell array to store the features extracted from each file.

Comment: @Amro: Thanks, added two more examples to explain this a bit.

Comment: @ Mehrwolf: thanks, but my feature vector is not a single element. Its a matrix. That means for every wave file I will be generating a [8,10] matrix and have to store for every file. could you please let me know how?

Comment: I have already posted a version with a cell array, which can store arbitrary data per file. Just give it a try!